# Bash, Windows 10, Java - No such file or directory for Java application

Tags: java, bash, powershell

I'm trying to execute a Java file I was given on Windows 10, inside of the Bash shell.

I open my command prompt. I enter bash.

I set

```
JAVA_CALL="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java"
```

I try to execute the call, but to no luck. I read several threads on here and tried several things. I made sure my path includes both the Program Files x86 and the regular Program Files version of my JAVA.

I executed

```
sudo ln -s -f /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java.exe /bin/java
```

To try and make a link to it. I cannot get it to wrong. It always tells me

```
-bash: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I am sure that file exists. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Windows slash escaped "\\" instead of Unix slash "/".  I find that directory names with spaces in them are always a problem.  Maybe you can install Java in c:/Tools/Java or something without a space.

Comment: Don't crosspost: https://superuser.com/q/1392404/340330

Comment: Why have you added the powershell tag, when we are talking about a bash? Is the bash stand-alone or from the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: Have you tried to execute `/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java`?